# #1305 - FUNCTION DATENAME does not exist

Tags: mysql, function, date

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,created) AS bulan,
       COUNT(created) AS jumlah 
FROM ost_ticket 
GROUP BY bulan
```

I want to get the month name from column created that have type `DATETIME`. This is example data from column created `2014-02-04 09:55:22` but I got error function datename does not exist.

Comment: Which DBMS is this? The error code and message suggests MySQL

Comment: I think it is [SQL SERVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174395.aspx)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
select MONTHNAME(created) from tablename;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Answer (score 3):

`DATENAME` is a SQL-Server function. It doesn't exist in MySQL.

Use `DATE_FORMAT(created,'%M')` instead

Comment: Could also try [`MONTHNAME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  DATE_FORMAT(created,'%b')
```

to get month name in abbreviated form as Jan , Feb etc..

```
DATE_FORMAT(created,'%M')
```

gives full month name January , March etc.

[**More formatting options here**](http://www.suhailkaleem.com/mssql-datename-alternative-for-mysql/)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created,'%M') AS bulan,
       COUNT(created) AS jumlah 
FROM ost_ticket 
GROUP BY bulan
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [month](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) function to get the month from a date for SQL_SERVER.

```
select month(created) from table_name;
```